# Error when removing selected items from a listbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, listbox

**Scenario**

I have 2 listboxes 1 for an order and another for the total cost. To make it user to use i used the following code to link up the selected items.

```
Dim Selecting As Boolean = False
Private Sub lstOrders_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstOrders.SelectedIndexChanged
    If Not Selecting Then
        Selecting = True
        lstTotalsEachOrder.SetSelected(lstOrders.SelectedIndex, True)
        Selecting = False
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub lstTotalsEachOrder_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstTotalsEachOrder.SelectedIndexChanged
    If Not Selecting Then
        Selecting = True
        lstOrders.SetSelected(lstTotalsEachOrder.SelectedIndex, True)
        Selecting = False
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem comes in when i attempt to remove an item use the following code.

```
        lstOrders.Items.RemoveAt(lstOrders.Items.Count - 1)
        lstTotalsEachOrder.Items.RemoveAt(lstTotalsEachOrder.Items.Count - 1)
```

**The Problem**

It works fine removing items, but when it reaches a selected item it throws the error: InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.

I attempted to fix this using the following code

```
lstOrders.ClearSelected()
lstTotalsEachOrder.ClearSelected()
```

But i still get the error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If it does not like `-1` you can test for that condition before running the code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the problem is with the selected items?
Seems to me that you are getting this exception after you try to remove items from an empty `ListBox`.

Use a simple condition to make sure the `ListBox` actually have items inside:

```
If lstOrders.Items.Count > 0 Then 
    lstOrders.Items.RemoveAt(lstOrders.Items.Count - 1)
End If
If lstTotalsEachOrder.Items.Count > 0 Then 
    lstTotalsEachOrder.Items.RemoveAt(lstTotalsEachOrder.Items.Count - 1)
End If
```

Of course, you can wrap it all in a sub like this:

```
Sub RemoveLastItem(byVal lst as ListBox)
    If lst.Items.Count > 0 Then 
        lst.Items.RemoveAt(lst.Items.Count - 1)
    End if
End Sub
```

and then simply call this sub from your code:

```
RemoveLastItem(lstOrders)
RemoveLastItem(lstTotalsEachOrder)
```

Comment: im sure, ill try your solution ina bit, for example i could have 10 items, and the selected item could be number 9, deletes 10 fine but throws the error for 9

Comment: You are giving this snippet In which event ?? on selected index changed? or in another button click?

Comment: Where ever you want it, I'm sure you know better then me when you want to remove items from your listbox...

Comment: In the listbox i could select any item with it, whether it be in the middle begining or the end, i would click "remove" and the last item added would be deleted until it reaches the selected item where it throws this error

Comment: I belive if i found a way to execute: lstOrders.ClearSelected()
        lstTotalsEachOrder.ClearSelected(), simultaneously there would be a problem. I've attached these lines of could to a button and get the same error

Comment: Do you remove the last item on the selected changed event?

Answer (score 0):

As your Error message says:

> InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.

Which indicates that you are trying to remove the `ListItem` @ -1th index. which is not present in the collection. I hope that this will happens only when you are trying to delete some items when the list box is empty(ie., `lstOrders.Items.Count=0`)

hence `lstOrders.Items.RemoveAt(lstOrders.Items.Count - 1)` it result in removing the item @ -1th index.

> And also you have to notice that your code will always delete the last
>   item from the Listbox.

**My suggestion:**
You can avoid this by using the above suggestion, or in simple you can use `[SelectedIndex][1]` property of a `ListBox` to find and deleted the selected value.

Comment: i could have 20 items in the listbox, the error will appear only when a selected item is going to be deleted, i want it to delete the last items in the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem occured because there was sum sort of mismatch in the code. The error was thrown in the following code

```
 Dim Selecting As Boolean = False
Private Sub lstOrders_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstOrders.SelectedIndexChanged
    If Not Selecting Then
        Selecting = True
        lstTotalsEachOrder.SetSelected(lstOrders.SelectedIndex, True)
        Selecting = False
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub lstTotalsEachOrder_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstTotalsEachOrder.SelectedIndexChanged
    If Not Selecting Then
        Selecting = True
        lstOrders.SetSelected(lstTotalsEachOrder.SelectedIndex, True)
        Selecting = False
    End If
End Sub
```

So i though if i attempted to deselect the times then remove the item it would be fine so i wrote this before removing the items

```
lstOrders.ClearSelected()
lstTotalsEachOrder.ClearSelected()
```

But still the error occured, so i attached the following code to a button and this was also triggering the error. So i fixed this by doing the following,

```
    Selecting = True

    lstOrders.ClearSelected()
    lstTotalsEachOrder.ClearSelected()

    Selecting = False
```

This allowed me to deselect the items and remove them from the listbox's.